# Gradle Groovy project Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: eclipse, gradle, groovy, command-line-interface

I was able to finally get a Gradle application project working with Eclipse. (For some odd reason, when you use Eclipse to create Gradle project, it creates a library (i.e. non-executable) one, and has no options to choose other project forms.)

I'm able to not only get it working in Eclipse (i.e. no errors when I "Refresh Gradle project"), but am able to `gradle clean build` it as well.

However, when I try to `gradle run` it, I face issue:

```
$ gradle run --args="--jsonConfig cliConfig.json"

> Task :lib:run FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class com.signaturemd.sposZohoMergeScript.App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.signaturemd.sposZohoMergeScript.App
```

The `build.gradle` lives in child `lib` folder, and is defined to be:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

application { 
    mainClass = 'com.signaturemd.sposZohoMergeScript.App'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

// SOURCE: ChatGPT AI
task createJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.signaturemd.sposZohoMergeScript.App'
    }
    baseName = 'SposZohoMergeScript' // deprecated
    from(sourceSets.main.output) {
        include '**/*'
    }
    with jar
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'

    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    // api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.groovy/groovy-cli-commons
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-cli-commons:4.0.9'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.groovy/groovy-json
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-json:4.0.9'
    
    
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and my project structure, which I didn't change from Eclipse Gradle project structure, is like this:

[image]

Also, `settings.gradle`, which lives in project root folder, was not modified in any way from what Eclipse Gradle plugin generated:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * The settings file is used to specify which projects to include in your build.
 *
 * Detailed information about configuring a multi-project build in Gradle can be found
 * in the user manual at https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
 */

rootProject.name = 'com.signaturemd.sposZohoMergeScript'
include('lib')
```

What am I doing wrong in my `build.gradle` file or my project structure?

Comment: You seem to have not instructed Gradle to do anything related to groovy, neither declared that you need the groovy plug-in, nor put your groovy sources into src/main/groovy.

Comment: Is [this plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) what I should use?

Comment: In your `build.gradle`, in `plugins { ... }` there should also be `id 'groovy'`. And your Groovy source files should be in `src/main/groovy`, not in `src/main/java` (same for your test code): see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html

Comment: @howlger I make those changes you suggest, and everything breaks. 

It's saying it's unable to resolve a class that is part of a third-party library I already imported in `dependencies`

Comment: Well, you have the Groovy code in `src/main/java` which seems wrong to me and which is also against what is documented here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html Also, without `id 'groovy'` Gradle will ignore your Groovy code causing all Groovy code related problems to be hidden (insert an error in your Groovy code and you will see whether it will be ignored or not).

Comment: UPDATE: turns out the error was due to actual dependency not being there. I updated it, was able to `gradle clean build` it, and it worked. 

However, I am facing different issue this time, and it looks like it's coming from my actual code... I tested it, it shouldn't be happening, but different error typically means I'm making progress

Comment: I'm counting this as issue solved, because it's actual code issues. 

I'ma detail everything I did to `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

As @nitind and @howlger pointed out, I need to tell Gradle that I am using Groovy, not Java.

I make the following changes to my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy' // added line
    id 'application'
    id 'eclipse' // added line
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy']

dependencies { 

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli
    implementation 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.5.0' // missing dependency, somehow it was there prior
}
```

I'm facing actual code issues, but that's outside the scope of this question.